# How to update variable in single element of struct list

Tags: c#, list, struct

I`ve got a struct that includes numeral variable

```
public struct A
{
    public int x;
    public string y;
}
```

Also i have a List of a struct type:`List<A> l = new List<A>()`

After adding noumerus elements into the list, a want to set a value to variable y but only for the element where x=1

I am able to find the element in the list that fullfill the condition

```
l.Find(item => item.x == 1)
```

how i can to set the value of y for that specific element`?
I tryed the elementary way (from my opinion) but it wrong

```
l.Find(item => item.x == 1).y="valueX"
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you considered *not* using a struct, or making the struct immutable? (Yes there are ways of doing this, but I wouldn't recommend them.)

Comment: Don't try to change values of a a struct. That's a road to nowhere. You want a class.

Comment: Since you have meaningless names anyway, maybe you are looking for a `Dictionary<int, string>` instead. Then it's easy: `dict[1] = "valueX";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect example why using [mutable strcuts is pure evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil). Basically whenever your values might change you should consider to use a class instead of struct.

As of [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229031(v=vs.110).aspx):

> X DO NOT define mutable value types

The problem you got arises from the fact that structs are value-types which get copied whenever passed to or returned from a member - in your case `List.Find`. Thus any updates to the instance you recieved via `Find` won´t be reflected to the instance within the list. You could strangly bypass this by using an array instead of a list, but that´s also a bad idea as it hides the actual problem.